# Icons show up as html tags in R shiny

Tags: r, shiny

So I am trying to use icons to show changes in a r shiny app. I can share the portion of the code I am using to generate the icons and for some reason when I user renderUI it generates `<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-circle-arrow-up text-success fa-lg"></i>` instead  of the icon.

```
 gicon <- function(x) as.character(icon(x, lib = "glyphicon"))

funcA <-function(){
       change <- 
        ifelse(
        a < b,
       gicon("circle-arrow-up text-success fa-lg"),
       gicon("circle-arrow-down text-danger fa-lg"))
      change
    }
```

Output:

```
 output$firstChange <- renderUI({ 
          paste( 450,funcA())
        })
```

UI

```
firstUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  htmlOutput(ns("firstChange"))
}
```

How can I get the icon instead of the tag.

Comment: Maybe `HTML(paste(450, funcA()))`

Comment: Jeez, I missed that .. Thank you. Thats the answer :)